# Recommended Settings/Properties for Windows Forms

Tags: windows, forms

Are there are recommended settings available for Windows Forms? For example, properties recommended for Windows Forms, DataGridView controls, etc.

Thanks,
Nratwa

Answer (score 0):

There are no recommended settings for these objects in Windows Forms. If you are worried about changing too much, just stick with the default properties unless you actually need to change them.

Are you looking for naming conventions? http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms/naming-your-controls This is a good place to start if you want your code to be readable and familiar to other people who frequently code using Windows Forms.

Comment: Thanks!, Do you have a list of default properties that I can use for Windows Forms? There are several reasons as to why I ask for recommended properties as listed below: 1. I see controls flashing/flickering when operating or re-sizing Application. 2. DataGridView opens slow or painting is too slow, etc. At first place, how do I prevent controls from flashing/flickering when opening the application?

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issues when using a DataGridView. To my knowledge, the flickering is caused by how complex it is to paint a DataGridView object. I don't know what your DataGridView is getting its data from, but changing the property called "VirtualMode" from False to True might help.

Otherwise, you can call SuspendLayout() before you begin to change a lot of data or change your window. Then call ResumeLayout() when you are done.